# Replace objects in json with their sum using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

Trying to solve the problem, but even don't know how to start.
I have json like this

```
[
  {
    "Count": "226",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "224",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "3",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "6",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "233",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "7",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  }
]
```

And I need to get sum of counters for distinct Action where Status > 1. Result should replace summarized elements.
Example of result:

```
[
  {
    "Count": "226",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "227",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "233",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "7",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  }
]
```

As you can see, field Count in element with "Action": "1" and "Status": "2" was increased on value of object with "Action": "1" and "Status": "6"

I don't know how to do it. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This would be easier to work with and think about if your output structure was -- even just temporarily -- indexed by action. If you could get away with it, I would also drop all data that isn't intended to go into the calculation.

Comment: BTW, how is it supposed to be determined that the `"Status": 2` item and not the `"Status": 6` one is retained and updated? Similarly, what should happen if you have conflicting `Client` values -- pick one and throw away the others, or is there a more nuanced behavior desired?

Comment: Picking an output data structure that doesn't _include_ extra, potentially-conflicting data is going to make your code shorter/cleaner; it's not just a cleanliness-of-design concern.

Comment: `[.[] | select((.Status|tonumber)>1)] | reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item.Action] += ($item.Count | tonumber))`, as an example of something with an output format chosen for simplicity/clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution aggregates into the first items within each duplicate list (which is not obvious from your sample data, see the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712566/replace-objects-in-json-with-their-sum-using-jq/70712762#comment125007513_70712566)).

`group_by` groups the items to aggregate, which is determined by a `.Status` greater `1` and the content of `.Action`. Then, with `map` each grouped list's first (`.[0]`) item's `.Count` field is calculated by `add`ing up all `.Count` fields' values. The output within each group is the first (`.[0]`) element.

```sh
jq '
  group_by([(.Status | tonumber > 1), .Action])
  | map(.[0].Count = (map(.Count | tonumber) | add | tostring) | .[0])
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "Count": "226",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "233",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "1",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "227",
    "Action": "1",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  },
  {
    "Count": "7",
    "Action": "2",
    "Status": "2",
    "Client": "26"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HN9SxM8RfV)

As `.Status` and `.Count` are strings, not numbers, it was necessary to convert them back and forth using `tonumber` and `tostring`. You may want to, especially if you have more calculations to process, first convert them into numbers, then do all the (now simpler) processing, and finally convert them back (if necessary).

```sh
jq '
  map((.Status, .Count) |= tonumber)
  | group_by([(.Status > 1), .Action])
  | map(.[0].Count = (map(.Count) | add) | .[0])
  | map((.Status, .Count) |= tostring)
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nDHuiVMeQz)

Comment: It's a very smart and brilliant answer that solves my problem. Thanks a lot!